# SwiftUI go back programmatically from representable to View

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

I'm trying to setup a qr reader within a new swift ui app.

I can get load the UIKit qr reader view with this line

`NavigationLink(destination: QRCodeScan()){Text("Scan QR")}`

This is my ViewControllerRepresentable

```
struct QRCodeScan: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ScannerViewController {
    let vc = ScannerViewController()
    vc.delegate = context.coordinator
    return vc
}

func updateUIViewController(_ vc: ScannerViewController, context: Context) {
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, QRCodeScannerDelegate {
    func codeDidFind(_ code: String) {
        print(code)
        //Go back to the last page, take 'code' with you
    }

    var parent: QRCodeScan

    init(_ parent: QRCodeScan) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
}
```

}

At the line 'Go back to the last page...' I need to programmatically return to the page which sent the user to the qr scanner. The page loads with a navigation back button, I pretty much need to replicate this buttons behaviour to call when I need

Any help/pointers appreciated

tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't do that right now. There is neither a binding nor an environment value to set that can trigger this. My guess is there will be some kind of environment value akin to `presentationMode` that you can tap into but it isn't currently advertised.

You could try the current `presentationMode` but my real suggestion is to present your QR scanner as a sheet rather than a push. This may actually make more sense from a navigational standpoint anyway. To do it this way, in your presenter set up a `@State` var to handle when it's presented.

```
@State var presentQRScanner = false

var body: some View {
    Button("Scan") {
        self.presentQRScanner = true
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $presentQRScanner) { QRCodeScan() }
}
```

Then, when you want to programmatically dismiss, your `UIViewControllerRepresentable`:

```swift
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

func scannedCode() {
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```

Alternatively, you can drive this from the presenter too by creating a closure on the QRCodeScan that gets invoked with the code and you have your presenter dismiss.

```swift
var onCodeScanned: (Code) -> Void = { _ in }

func scannedCode() {
    onCodeScanned(code)
}
```

and in the presenter:

```
var body: some View {
    Button("Scan") {
        self.presentQRScanner = true
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $presentQRScanner) { 
        QRCodeScan(onCodeScanned: { 
            self.process($0)
            self.presentQRScanner = false
        })
    }
}
```

EDIT: was not aware of the `isActive` binding, that should actually work for you if you still want to push your view on the nav stack instead of present it.

Comment: Thanks, went with your advice and changed how the view is presented, now need to get the 'code' back from the modal view.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isActive = false
    @State var code = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(isActive: $isActive, code: $code), isActive: $isActive, label: { EmptyView() })
                Button(action: {
                    self.isActive.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("navigate")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
struct DetailView: View {

    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    @Binding var code: String

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.code = "new code"
            self.isActive.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Back")
        }
    }
}
```

This might help you, use `isActive` parameter of NavigationLink to navigate back and forth

Comment: I believe this approach above is preferred way of doing it. Existing SwiftUI API commonly works by taking a binding to isVisible (eg. Alerts) and dismisses it by setting it to false on dismiss. Maniplulation through *presentation* on the other hand seems common now, but to me it feels like it deviates from SwiftUI's declarative style.

Comment: Yes, the way I’m reading this answer however doesn’t actually solve my problem, it still adds a button to screen 2 that the user has to press to go back, that wasn’t what I was looking for, I already had a button for that, I needed a way to invoke this action in an event handler

Comment: @robbo5899 at the line "//Go back to the last page, take 'code' with you" add `self.code = "new code"
            self.isActive.toggle()`, I just used a button to show you how it works

Comment: Ah ok thanks, seems to be a little more awkward doing it with the Representable and getting the data out of the coordinator, great help thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following overload of the `NavigationLink`. It's available since iOS 13 and later.

Here's the code.

Pay attention to passing `$isShowingView` binding to the both `NavigationLink` object and to the `ChildView` that you want to go out on button tap.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isShowingChildView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(isActive: $isShowingChildView) {
                ChildView(isShowingView: $isShowingChildView)
            } label: {
                Text("Open new view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
        
    @Binding
    var isShowingView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Back to parent view") {
                isShowingView = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To go back just add the `presentaionMode` property into the `QRCodeScan`:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
```

And when your delegate executes - need to call the following:

```
parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

So the full code will look the following way:

```
struct QRCodeScan: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }

  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ScannerViewController {
    let vc = ScannerViewController()
    vc.delegate = context.coordinator
    return vc
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ vc: ScannerViewController, context: Context) {
  }

  class Coordinator: NSObject, QRCodeScannerDelegate {
    func codeDidFind(_ code: String) {
        //Go back to the last page, take 'code' with you
        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }

    var parent: QRCodeScan

    init(_ parent: QRCodeScan) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
}
```